# How to Enable/Disable session based on url using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, session, express

I use express and express-session middleware to build a website, with session enabled. But some url such as `/health-check' and`/version-check`do not need session, especially the`/health-check`, which will generate a lot of useless session in db(the project use mongodb).I believe there is a good solution to solve the problem.

The following is a snippets of the session:

```
var session = require('express-session'),
    passport = require('passport');

var app = express();
//other middleware.

// Express MongoDB session storage
app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2628000000 },
    store: new mongoStore({
        db: db.connection.db,
        collection: config.sessionCollection
    })
}));

// use passport session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create own middleware function and put there your session middleware as function, but with conditions e.g:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(...some condition...){//for example check url
    //do something or nothing
    next();//very important or request will freeze
  } else {//otherwise run session
    session({your options})(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

instead your app.use(session())

in one custom middleware you can put any other middleware to add conditions. But when you want to wrap more then one middleware to single custom middleware be careful on 'next'. It can be use only once in middleware (multiple middlewares use use it multiple time). Then you have to create your own callback 'next'.